# Unable to start Elastic Search 8 and Kibana using Docker

Tags: docker, elasticsearch, kibana

I used the following procedure to install Elastic Search and Kibana 8 RC2 :

```
# create the data directory on host for persistence
mkdir -p /data/elasticsearch/data
chmod 777 -R /data/elasticsearch/data

# create the elastic network
docker network create elastic

# run elastic search in background with data persistence in a single node configuration and test password
docker run -d -it --name els01 --net elastic -p 0.0.0.0:9200:9200 -p 0.0.0.0:9300:9300 -v /data/elasticsearch/data:/data/elasticsearch/data -e "discovery.type=single-node" -e ELASTIC_PASSWORD="test" -e KIBANA_PASSWORD="test" docker.elastic.co/elasticsearch/elasticsearch:8.0.0-rc2

# run kibana in background 
docker run -d -it --name kib01 --net elastic -p 0.0.0.0:5601:5601 -e KIBANA_PASSWORD="test" -e "ELASTICSEARCH_HOSTS=https://els01:9200" docker.elastic.co/kibana/kibana:8.0.0-rc2
```

On the webpage http://10.0.2.1:5601/, I get this error :
*Kibana server is not ready yet.*

`docker logs --tail 50 --follow --timestamps f82efc804e9c` returns this error :
*Unable to retrieve version information from Elasticsearch nodes. self signed certificate in certificate chain*

What do I need to change in order to have a functionnal Kibana on Elastic Search ?

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

## TLDR;

Elasticsearch 8 comes with [SSL/TLS enabled by default](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/release-highlights.html#_security_features_are_enabled_and_configured_by_default)
Kibana has to have the CA certificate to verify and connect to elasticsearch.

## To solve

How about you use the [docker-compose file provided to set up a multi-cluster node](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/docker.html#docker-compose-file). It will take care of the SSL/TLS certificate.

You will just need to

- delete services `es02` and `es03`
- update volumes path
  to be back on your actual set up.

This could look like

```
version: "2.2"

services:
  setup:
    image: docker.elastic.co/elasticsearch/elasticsearch:${STACK_VERSION}
    volumes:
      - certs:/usr/share/elasticsearch/config/certs
    user: "0"
    command: >
      bash -c '
        if [ x${ELASTIC_PASSWORD} == x ]; then
          echo "Set the ELASTIC_PASSWORD environment variable in the .env file";
          exit 1;
        elif [ x${KIBANA_PASSWORD} == x ]; then
          echo "Set the KIBANA_PASSWORD environment variable in the .env file";
          exit 1;
        fi;
        if [ ! -f certs/ca.zip ]; then
          echo "Creating CA";
          bin/elasticsearch-certutil ca --silent --pem -out config/certs/ca.zip;
          unzip config/certs/ca.zip -d config/certs;
        fi;
        if [ ! -f certs/certs.zip ]; then
          echo "Creating certs";
          echo -ne \
          "instances:\n"\
          "  - name: es01\n"\
          "    dns:\n"\
          "      - es01\n"\
          "      - localhost\n"\
          "    ip:\n"\
          "      - 127.0.0.1\n"\
          > config/certs/instances.yml;
          bin/elasticsearch-certutil cert --silent --pem -out config/certs/certs.zip --in config/certs/instances.yml --ca-cert config/certs/ca/ca.crt --ca-key config/certs/ca/ca.key;
          unzip config/certs/certs.zip -d config/certs;
        fi;
        echo "Setting file permissions"
        chown -R root:root config/certs;
        find . -type d -exec chmod 750 \{\} \;;
        find . -type f -exec chmod 640 \{\} \;;
        echo "Waiting for Elasticsearch availability";
        until curl -s --cacert config/certs/ca/ca.crt https://es01:9200 | grep -q "missing authentication credentials"; do sleep 30; done;
        echo "Setting kibana_system password";
        until curl -s -X POST --cacert config/certs/ca/ca.crt -u elastic:${ELASTIC_PASSWORD} -H "Content-Type: application/json" https://es01:9200/_security/user/kibana_system/_password -d "{\"password\":\"${KIBANA_PASSWORD}\"}" | grep -q "^{}"; do sleep 10; done;
        echo "All done!";
      '
    healthcheck:
      test: ["CMD-SHELL", "[ -f config/certs/es01/es01.crt ]"]
      interval: 1s
      timeout: 5s
      retries: 120

  es01:
    depends_on:
      setup:
        condition: service_healthy
    image: docker.elastic.co/elasticsearch/elasticsearch:${STACK_VERSION}
    volumes:
      - certs:/usr/share/elasticsearch/config/certs
      - type: bind
        source: /data/elasticsearch/data
        target: /usr/share/elasticsearch/data
    ports:
      - ${ES_PORT}:9200
    environment:
      - node.name=es01
      - cluster.name=${CLUSTER_NAME}
      - cluster.initial_master_nodes=es01,es02,es03
      - discovery.seed_hosts=es02,es03
      - ELASTIC_PASSWORD=${ELASTIC_PASSWORD}
      - bootstrap.memory_lock=true
      - xpack.security.enabled=true
      - xpack.security.http.ssl.enabled=true
      - xpack.security.http.ssl.key=certs/es01/es01.key
      - xpack.security.http.ssl.certificate=certs/es01/es01.crt
      - xpack.security.http.ssl.certificate_authorities=certs/ca/ca.crt
      - xpack.security.http.ssl.verification_mode=certificate
      - xpack.security.transport.ssl.enabled=true
      - xpack.security.transport.ssl.key=certs/es01/es01.key
      - xpack.security.transport.ssl.certificate=certs/es01/es01.crt
      - xpack.security.transport.ssl.certificate_authorities=certs/ca/ca.crt
      - xpack.security.transport.ssl.verification_mode=certificate
      - xpack.license.self_generated.type=${LICENSE}
    mem_limit: ${MEM_LIMIT}
    ulimits:
      memlock:
        soft: -1
        hard: -1
    healthcheck:
      test:
        [
          "CMD-SHELL",
          "curl -s --cacert config/certs/ca/ca.crt https://localhost:9200 | grep -q 'missing authentication credentials'",
        ]
      interval: 10s
      timeout: 10s
      retries: 120

  kibana:
    depends_on:
      es01:
        condition: service_healthy
      es02:
        condition: service_healthy
      es03:
        condition: service_healthy
    image: docker.elastic.co/kibana/kibana:${STACK_VERSION}
    volumes:
      - certs:/usr/share/kibana/config/certs
      - kibanadata:/usr/share/kibana/data
    ports:
      - ${KIBANA_PORT}:5601
    environment:
      - SERVERNAME=kibana
      - ELASTICSEARCH_HOSTS=https://es01:9200
      - ELASTICSEARCH_USERNAME=kibana_system
      - ELASTICSEARCH_PASSWORD=${KIBANA_PASSWORD}
      - ELASTICSEARCH_SSL_CERTIFICATEAUTHORITIES=config/certs/ca/ca.crt
    mem_limit: ${MEM_LIMIT}
    healthcheck:
      test:
        [
          "CMD-SHELL",
          "curl -s -I http://localhost:5601 | grep -q 'HTTP/1.1 302 Found'",
        ]
      interval: 10s
      timeout: 10s
      retries: 120

volumes:
  certs:
    driver: local
  esdata01:
    driver: local
  kibanadata:
    driver: local
```

Comment: What do you mean by "update volumes path to be back on your actual set up." I'm having the same issues as OP.

Comment: OP is creating a folder `/data/elasticsearch/data` on the Host and then mount it in the container. Where in my exemple I do not. If you still want your data to be persisted on a volume I believe you have to update in my docker compose file the path for the volume.

Comment: I have lightly edited the compose file: https://pastebin.com/GihJ9TRA
I get:
> ERROR: for elasticsearch  Container "3a35b3b44bb5" is unhealthy.
> ERROR: Encountered errors while bringing up the project.t
Any ideas how to fix that?

Comment: please open another question with all details

Answer (score 0):

My version for single node configuration and without env variables:

```
version: "2.2"

services:
  setup:
    image: docker.elastic.co/elasticsearch/elasticsearch:8.3.3
    volumes:
      - ./volumes/data/es/certs:/usr/share/elasticsearch/config/certs
    user: "0"
    command: >
      bash -c '
        if [ ! -f certs/ca.zip ]; then
          echo "Creating CA";
          bin/elasticsearch-certutil ca --silent --pem -out config/certs/ca.zip;
          unzip config/certs/ca.zip -d config/certs;
        fi;
        if [ ! -f certs/certs.zip ]; then
          echo "Creating certs";
          echo -ne \
          "instances:\n"\
          "  - name: es01\n"\
          "    dns:\n"\
          "      - es01\n"\
          "      - localhost\n"\
          "    ip:\n"\
          "      - 127.0.0.1\n"\
          > config/certs/instances.yml;
          bin/elasticsearch-certutil cert --silent --pem -out config/certs/certs.zip --in config/certs/instances.yml --ca-cert config/certs/ca/ca.crt --ca-key config/certs/ca/ca.key;
          unzip config/certs/certs.zip -d config/certs;
        fi;
        echo "Setting file permissions"
        chown -R root:root config/certs;
        find . -type d -exec chmod 750 \{\} \;;
        find . -type f -exec chmod 640 \{\} \;;
        echo "Waiting for Elasticsearch availability";
        until curl -s --cacert config/certs/ca/ca.crt https://es01:9200 | grep -q "missing authentication credentials"; do sleep 30; done;
        echo "Setting kibana_system password";
        until curl -s -X POST --cacert config/certs/ca/ca.crt -u elastic:E0glIRkUbVak8f4aHZe -H "Content-Type: application/json" https://es01:9200/_security/user/kibana_system/_password -d "{\"password\":\"E0glIRkUbVak8f4aHZk\"}" | grep -q "^{}"; do sleep 10; done;
        echo "All done!";
      '
    healthcheck:
      test: ["CMD-SHELL", "[ -f config/certs/es01/es01.crt ]"]
      interval: 1s
      timeout: 5s
      retries: 120

  es01:
    depends_on:
      setup:
        condition: service_healthy
    image: docker.elastic.co/elasticsearch/elasticsearch:8.3.3
    volumes:
      - ./volumes/data/es/certs:/usr/share/elasticsearch/config/certs
      - ./volumes/data/es/es01:/usr/share/elasticsearch/data
    ports:
      - 9200:9200
    environment:
      - node.name=es01
      - discovery.type=single-node
      - ELASTIC_PASSWORD=<ELASTIC_PASSWORD>
      - bootstrap.memory_lock=true
      - xpack.security.enabled=true
      - xpack.security.http.ssl.enabled=true
      - xpack.security.http.ssl.key=certs/es01/es01.key
      - xpack.security.http.ssl.certificate=certs/es01/es01.crt
      - xpack.security.http.ssl.certificate_authorities=certs/ca/ca.crt
      - xpack.security.http.ssl.verification_mode=certificate
      - xpack.security.transport.ssl.enabled=true
      - xpack.security.transport.ssl.key=certs/es01/es01.key
      - xpack.security.transport.ssl.certificate=certs/es01/es01.crt
      - xpack.security.transport.ssl.certificate_authorities=certs/ca/ca.crt
      - xpack.security.transport.ssl.verification_mode=certificate
      - xpack.license.self_generated.type=basic
    mem_limit: 1073741824
    ulimits:
      memlock:
        soft: -1
        hard: -1
    healthcheck:
      test:
        [
          "CMD-SHELL",
          "curl -s --cacert config/certs/ca/ca.crt https://localhost:9200 | grep -q 'missing authentication credentials'",
        ]
      interval: 10s
      timeout: 10s
      retries: 120

  kibana:
    depends_on:
      es01:
        condition: service_healthy
    image: docker.elastic.co/kibana/kibana:8.3.3
    volumes:
      - ./volumes/data/es/certs:/usr/share/kibana/config/certs
      - ./volumes/data/es/kibanadata:/usr/share/kibana/data
    ports:
      - 5601:5601
    environment:
      - SERVERNAME=kibana
      - ELASTICSEARCH_HOSTS=https://es01:9200
      - ELASTICSEARCH_USERNAME=kibana_system
      - ELASTICSEARCH_PASSWORD=<KIBANA_SYSTEM_PASSWORD>
      - ELASTICSEARCH_SSL_CERTIFICATEAUTHORITIES=config/certs/ca/ca.crt
    mem_limit: 1073741824
    healthcheck:
      test:
        [
          "CMD-SHELL",
          "curl -s -I http://localhost:5601 | grep -q 'HTTP/1.1 302 Found'",
        ]
      interval: 10s
      timeout: 10s
      retries: 120
```